# Recurrence relations, analyze algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, recurrence

Alright I have some difficulty completely understanding recurrence relations.

So for example if I'm analyzing quick sort in the worst case using Θ-notation, giving the array an input of unsorted positive numbers;

When base case n <= 3 I sort the small array using insertionsort.
Time: O(1) or O(n^2)?

I use linear search to set the pivot as the median of all elements.
Time: Θ(n)

Partitioning left and right of pivot and performing recursion.
Time: 2 * T(n/2) I think

would the recurrence be:
T(n) = O(1) + Θ(n) + 2 * T(n/2) then?

Something tells me the base case would instead take O(n^2) time because if the input is small enough that would be the worst case.
Would that then give me the recurrence:
T(n) = O(n^2) + Θ(n) + 2 * T(n/2)?

Comment: if n <=3, whatever you sort, you can think as O(1). The worst case is the pivot is always 1 and n-1(any n), then it be: T(n) = O(n) + T(n-1). then T(n) = O(n) + O(n-1) + O(n-2)...+O(1), thus T(n) = O(n^2)

Comment: But the only time the algorithm has O(n^2) is when the entire input has the same numbers, since the pivot in this case cannot be first or last. So I wonder, if I'm using Θ-notation to describe the recurrence, should I then consider the avarage worst case or the actual worst case?

Answer (score 2):

1. When base case n <= 3 I sort the small array using insertionsort.

   - always *O(1)*
2. I use linear search to set the pivot as the median of all elements.

   - You may want to clarify this more, to find the median as pivot is not a simple task of doing linear search. The few ways are i) using
     *Quick Select Algorithm* (average O(N)) or ii) *sorting the subpartition*
     O(NlogN) iii) *median-of-median algorithm* O(N).
3. Partitioning left and right of pivot and performing recursion.

   - 2F(N/2) + N

Putting it all together (Assuming that the pivot is always the median & that you take O(N) to find the pivot each time):

Best_Case = Worst_Case (since the pivot is always median)

```
F(3) = F(2) = F(1) = 1

F(n) = 2F(N/2) + 2N 
= 2(2F(N/2^2) + 2(N/2)) + 2N 
= 2(2)F(N/2^2) + 2N + 2N
= 2(3)F(N/2^3) + 3(2)N
= 2(LogN)F(N/N) + (2N)LogN
= O(NlogN)
```